# Cannot import packages starting with org in java (due to dependencies I guess)

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I'm trying to import a package (import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution;) in Java (I'm using NetBeans) in order to calculate a probability using normal distribution, however it's giving me an error (the package... does not exist).

I've searched on here, but haven't found anything.

Has anyone ever faced this issue before?

Comment: Did you add the jar to your build path?

Comment: no, don't even know i'd have to do it, or how to